# Regex: find all IN clause with number of arguments greater or equal to

Tags: regex

As an input I've got a plain SQL query smth like:

```
select * from (
    select * from Table where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,642,7,8,9)
        or another_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6, 34 ,7 , 8,9))
where yet_another_id in (1,2)
```

I want to find **all** IN clause statements where the amount of arguments passed in is greater than XXX.
So far I've came up with this solution.

```
 ^.*\s*+(?:in)+\s*+(\((?:\s*+\d+\s*+\,?+){XXX,}+\){1}).*$
```

where XXX is the number of arguments.
Obviously, the first part:

```
 ^.*
```

eats all IN clause statements except the last one. How can I fix that? Any suggestions how can I improve the regex?

Comment: updated the question and fixed one typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this here

```
\bin\b\s*(?:\((?:\s*\d+\s*\,?){5,}\))
```

So I removed some stuff from your expression and fixed an obvious error `(\(?:` where you escaped the wrong bracket.

The `\b` is a word boundary.

This is working now for me [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vgt6)

Comment: @Funtik I changed my answer and added also a link to Regexr a useful online testing tool.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be massively over complicating this with random `+` characters all over the place: `\s*+` means 0 or more spaces repeated one or more times. `\s*` is sufficient. Then `(?:in)+` means you want to match `in` or `ininininininininin` which doesn't seem right. Again the `\,?+` means an optional comma repeated one or more times.

The real problem however is that after the literal `\(` you have `?:` which isn't following open parentheses so that means `\(?:` is matching an optional `(` followed by a non-optional `:`. You don't have any colons in the input so no possible matches.

Try something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = '''select * from (
    select * from Table where id in (1,2,3,4,5,6,642,7,8,9)
        or another_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6, 34 ,7 , 8,9))
where yet_another_id in (1,2)'''
>>> re.findall("(?:in)\s*(\((?:[^),]+\,?){10,}\))", text)
['(1,2,3,4,5,6,642,7,8,9)', '(1,2,3,4,5,6, 34 ,7 , 8,9)']
```

You may or may not need the extra `^.*?` and `.*$` around the regex depending on how you are using this.

Comment: thanks for the reply and for the hints
Yes, my solution by no means was an elegant one. I edited the question and fixed the typo regarding the brackets and optional group